# How can I take control of canEditRowAtIndexPath when using RxCocoa extension for UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reactive-programming, rx-swift

Just for the record before I launch into my question I am using Swift 2 and xcode 7 beta.

So I am using RxSwift and RxCocoa to bind my ViewModel to the TableView. In my `UITableViewController` `viewDidLoad` I am doing this binding...

```
someCollectionOfViewModels
    .bindTo(self.tableView.rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier("SomeCell")) { 
        (_, viewModel, cell: SomeTableViewCell) in
            cell.tripViewModel = viewModel
    }
```

`someCollectionOfViewModels` is just an array of view models wrapped in a `Variable<>`, so `Variable<[SomeViewModel]>.cell.tripViewModel` is of type `SomeViewModel`.

None of that is really pertinent to the problem, it all works great and when my view model updates, my table updates. The problem is that I want my table cells to be non-editable and the `UITableViewDataSource` that RxCocoa puts in place for the above binding doesn't implement the optional `canEditRowAtIndexPath` method on this protocol and it defaults to true making the cells editable. I know I can implement my own `RxTableViewDataSourceType` and that is fairly straightforward but a lot of code just to get this one little thing to work. I am fairly new to both RxSwift and iOS, am I missing something simple? Is there a way in the closure above where I have access to the `UITableCellView` to set some property on the cell itself to make it non-editable? How about something in the RxCocoa extensions that I am missing. If I have to I will go off and write my own `RxTableViewDataSource`, but I thought I would ask here first.

Thanks,

-Bill

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I [posted](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/354) this same question over in the Github project and received the answer. The key is to `rx_setDelegate(self)` and implement `UITableViewDelegate` like so:

```
class SimpleTableViewExampleViewController : ViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let items = Observable.just([
        "First Item",
        "Second Item",
        "Third Item"
    ])

    items
        .bindTo(tableView.rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier("Cell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)) { (row, element, cell) in
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(element) @ row \(row)"
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)


    tableView
        .rx_modelSelected(String)
        .subscribeNext { value in
            DefaultWireframe.presentAlert("Tapped `\(value)`")
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

    tableView.rx_setDelegate(self)
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
}
}
```

Thanks to Krunoslav Zaher in the RxSwift project for providing the answer.